# What is a good alternative to Firebase for user management, more specifically for Python?

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-storage, user-management, appery.io

What is an alternative to firebase for user management/auth for python apps. I know I can use node.js w/ firebase but, I would rather authenticate users through a managed 3rd party API in python using HTTPS requests,if possible. Appery.io has this feature but, I do not need all that comes with appery.io

Comment: I am looking for alternative too for user authentication. Someone pl suggest.

Comment: Firebase doesn't use HTTPS?

Answer (score 5):

Check out  [Amazon Cognito](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjphrjN7-PXAhUEhuAKHSABA14QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Faws.amazon.com%2Fcognito%2F&usg=AOvVaw0IxXy-fQjM_msyj67tH2wG) . They offer a quite nice package for small projects. [Backendless](http://backendless.com) is also a fantastic service, providing authentication and database with very helpful documentation and also SDK for different platforms including iOS, Android, Javascript, Rest API, Angular, React and React Native. I have been using Backendless for a couple of months and I highly recommend you use it, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a self-hosted solution, [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) is a pretty robust option. If you want a service, [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) and [Okta](https://okta.com/) have quite a lot of features. They also offer a free tier with reasonable limits.

Comment: Auth0 is acquired by Okta now

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) for pure authentication management. The Auth0 python package can be found [here](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-python).